# Mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given? Confusing?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  define('DB_USER', '******');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', '************');
  define('DB_NAME', '***********');

 $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

 class User {

 function checkUser($uid, $oauth_provider,$username,$email,$twitter_otoken,$twitter_otoken_secret) 
{
    $query = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM si_table WHERE oauth_uid = '$uid' and oauth_provider = '$oauth_provider'");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    if (!empty($result)) {
        # User is already present
    } else {
        #user not present. Insert a new Record
        $query = mysqli_query($dbc,"INSERT INTO si_table (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, user_name,email_id,twitter_oauth_token,twitter_oauth_token_secret) VALUES ('$oauth_provider', $uid, '$username','$email')") ;
        $query = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM si_table WHERE oauth_uid = '$uid' and oauth_provider = '$oauth_provider'");
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        return $result;
    }
    return $result;
}



}
```

I am getting this error! I don't know why?

> mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in line 14,15,20,21 and 22!

Comment: You should check the $dbc after mysqli_connect, it may fail.

Comment: @erenon, also true. but even if it didn't...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `global $dbc;` to the beginning of the `checkUser`. The variable is not defined in the function scope.

Comment: This works..but  I had a doubt..if $dbc was declared outside the class,(which by default makes it global) then why aggain make it global? I am sorry, if I am wrong..coz I am newbie..

Comment: Yes, it may be worth noting, that I only dealt with immediate problem.

Comment: @RobbieDc, this is how `php` works. Why using `php` is another question :)